# Random character change in a random place

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation, random

I would like to ask for help in a Random Replace of character. For example:

ORANGE and change 1 character randomly (random place and random character from ORANGE) in it into any character of ORANGE, for example OOANGE or ORNNGE, etc... All must be UpperCase.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 7):

```
StringReplacePart[
  #
  , RandomChoice[Characters@#]
  , {#, #} &@RandomInteger[{1, StringLength@#}]
 ] &@"ORANGE"
```

Answer (score 6):

This will change the first occurrence of a random char by another random char

```
f[s_] := StringReplace[s, Rule @@ RandomChoice[Characters@s, 2], 1]
f@"ORANGE"

(* "ORRNGE"*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly more involved approach that **always** changes a letter, or signals an error:

```
ClearAll[MutateString];

MutateString::nomut = "All characters in string `` are the same.";

MutateString[s_String] := 
 With[{choices = DeleteDuplicates[Characters[s]]}, 
  With[{n = RandomInteger[{1, StringLength[s]}]}, 
   StringReplacePart[s, RandomChoice[DeleteCases[choices, 
       StringTake[s, {n}]]], {n, n}] /; 2 <= Length[choices]]]

MutateString[s_String] /; Message[MutateString::nomut, s] || False := Null;
```

It's a little slow, but we can use it to see how many mutations it takes to turn all the characters in `"ORANGE"` the same:

```
mutationsUntilAllSame =
  Table[
   Quiet[
    Length@
      NestWhileList[Check[MutateString[#], $Failed] &, "ORANGE", 
       Not@*FailureQ, 1] - 2,
    MutateString::nomut],
   {10000}];

Histogram[
 mutationsUntilAllSame,
 Automatic,
 "PDF"]
```

[image: mutations]

Answer (score 4):

Experience shows that in order to understand a text it is by far not necessary that all ist letters to be correct.
Here's a little game to experiment with it.

We start with this text from Wikipedia:

```
t = "Mathematica is a symbolic mathematical computation program, \
sometimes called a computer algebra program, used in many scientific, \
engineering, mathematical, and computing fields. It was conceived by \
Stephen Wolfram and is developed by Wolfram Research of Champaign, \
Illinois. The Wolfram Language is the programming language used in \
Mathematica.";
```

Then define the replacement function slightly different from Belisarius in that each randomly generated replacement is carried out on each occurence in the whole text.

```
f[s_] := StringReplace[s, Rule @@ RandomChoice[Characters@s, 2]]
```

And then we repeat the replacements $n$ times using `Nest`.
Here we go

This Looks still English

```
Nest[f, t, 1]
```

> "Mathematica is symbolic mathematical computatioe program,  sometimes
>   called a computer algebra program, used ie maey scieetific,
>   eegieeerieg, mathematical, aed computieg fields. It was coeceived by
>   Stephee Wolfram aed is developed by Wolfram Research of Champaige,
>   Illieois. The Wolfram Laeguage is the programmieg laeguage used ie
>   Mathematica."

With two replacements it starts to get difficult

```
Nest[f, t, 2]
```

> "Mlthellticl is sylbolic llthellticll colputltion progrll, soletiles
>   cllled l colputer llgebrl progrll, used in llny scientific,
>   engineering, llthellticll, lnd colputing fields. It wls conceived by
>   Stephen Wolfrll lnd is developed by Wolfrll Reselrch of Chllplign,
>   Illinois. The Wolfrll Llngulge is the progrllling llngulge used in
>   Mlthellticl."

At `n = 3` a bit of Gaelic flavour develops

```
Nest[f, t, 3]
```

> "Mllhemllicl is symbolic mllhemllicll compulllion progrlm, somelimes
>   cllled l compuler llgebrl progrlm, used in mlny scienlific,
>   engineering, mllhemllicll, lnd compuling fields. Il uls conceived by
>   Slephen Wolfrlm lnd is developed by Wolfrlm Reselrch of Chlmplign,
>   Illinois. The Wolfrlm Llngulge is lhe progrlmming llngulge used in
>   Mllhemllicl."

And n = 5 is already unintelligible

```
Nest[f, t, 5]
```

> "Mvthelvt cv  s sslbol c lvthelvt cvl colputvt on progrvl, solet les
>   cvlled v colputer vlgebrv progrvl, used  n lvns sc ent f c, eng neer
>   ng, lvthelvt cvl, vnd colput ng f elds. It wvs conce ved bs Stephen
>   Wolfrvl vnd  s developed bs Wolfrvl Resevrch of Chvlpv gn, Ill no s.
>   The Wolfrvl Lvnguvge  s the progrvll ng lvnguvge used  n Mvthelvt
>   cv."

Comment: Except for the words "Stephen" and "developed"!

Comment: At `n = 5` it switches from Gaelic to Breton.

Comment: @march this can't have happened accidentally ;-)

Comment: @shrx I even have found examples of Nahuatl (native language of the Aztecs).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that excludes self-replacement.

```
Function[{s}, 
  StringReplacePart[s, StringTake[s, 
     ConstantArray[#[[1]], 2]], 
     ConstantArray[#[[2]], 2]] &@ 
       RandomSample[Range@StringLength@s, 2]]@"ORANGE"
```

(note you could end up with the same string in the case of repeated characters in the input)